# Specifying groups results in ugly geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting a moving average with two different colors depending on the value being between two specification limits. When I use one color, this works fine, but when I use two colors, this results in a blocked line.

The data:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(154,154.87,154.87,155,156,157,158,159,159.65,159.65,160,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170),
             y=c(-3.924,-9,-9,-9.73,-16.922,-18.066,-12.788,-13.676,-9,-9,-6.496,-2.458,0.696,3.406,4.458,-1.292,0.728,-1.962,-5.372,-7.408,-1.882),
             col=factor(c(3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)))
```

Now plotting in one single color, without group=1 option gives smooth transitions between segments:

```
gg <- ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))
gg <- gg + geom_line(color="blue",size=3)
gg <- gg + geom_hline(yintercept=c(-9,9),size=2)
gg
```

However, when introducing the group=1 (and the color=col) the transitions are not smooth anymore:

```
gg <- ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y,color=col,group=1))
gg <- gg + geom_line(size=3)
gg <- gg + geom_hline(yintercept=c(-9,9),size=2)
gg
```

What am I doing wrong or how can I solve this?

Comment: First image gives me a blue line, no transition. Am I missing something? How about setting the `col` to numeric? `color=as.numeric(as.character(col))`

Comment: Yes, indeed, the first image gives a blue line. This is the code where the image looks nice. But the second is what I am looking for, with different colors. This one does not look nice if you look closely... A numeric `col` gives me the same blocky transitions between **segments**, not expecially between the different colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're not necessarily doing something wrong, but it appears that ggplot cannot deal with a line belonging to one group (group=1) having multiple colours. Therefore, there appears to be some transformation to line segments which allows for color by group.

The quickest solution I could come up with was to also group by colour, and make the horizontal lines the same size as the plotted line (so they plot over horizontal parts of the line):

```
gg <- ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y,colour=col, group=col))
gg <- gg + geom_line(size=3)
gg <- gg + geom_hline(yintercept=c(-9,9),size=3)
gg
```

[image]

Edit: if line size is a problem (esthetically or not) you could add a grouping variable based on runs in the data with a small offset (offset not plotted)

```
df_runs <- rle(as.numeric(df$col))


#make group based on run lengths
df$group <- rep(1:length(df_runs$lengths),df_runs$lengths)

gg <- ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y,colour=col, group=group))
gg <- gg + geom_line(size=3)
gg <- gg + geom_hline(yintercept=c(-9,9),size=1)
gg
```

[image]

Comment: Your edit makes me happy! I suffered some problems with your first solution, because when the moving average later on goes above the upper spec, this gives me strange results. The creation of the group variable could me done easier by using the variable col: `#make group based on run lengths
df_runs <- rle(as.numeric(df$col))
df$group <- rep(1:length(df_runs$lengths),df_runs$lengths)`

Comment: You're welcome! And you're completely right, my brain was working in a different direction. I have edited my answer.